# Why isn't mongodump and mongorestore working?

Tags: mongodb

I am doing to following to sync mongodb database between two instances as follows but it doesn't seem to work,anyone know what should I do to fix it?

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb://username1:PASSWORD1@x.y.z.w:27017" --db=databaseName  --archive="mongodbdump.bson"


mongorestore --username=username2 --password=password2 --authenticationDatabase=databaseName --host=replicaset1:port1,replicaset2:port2,replicaset3:port3 --archive=mongodbdump.bson
```

Error:

```
0 document(s) restored successfully. 41419 document(s) failed to restore
```

Comment: No more information? Maybe use `--verbose` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an unique index conflict with the _id, you need to use the [--drop](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption-mongorestore-drop) option

> Before restoring the collections from the dumped backup, drops the
> collections from the target database. --drop does not drop collections
> that are not in the backup.